# Why is Instagram not using signed URLs?

Tags: amazon-s3, instagram, cdn, pre-signed-url

I was just dabbling a little with the Instagram API and noticed that all the media links (e.g. image / video URLs) that point to the fbcdn are publicly accessible.

**I usually try to use signed URLs for user-generated content and was wondering why Instagram apparently is not choosing to do that?**

If they would do that, the URLs that are used to render the webpage or the app for example could only be valid for a couple of minutes so if someone should collect them (for example to scrape user profiles) they wouldn't be accessible anymore afterwards? I know this is not perfect but it feels like it would at least give the privacy aspect a little extra notch...

Comment: I wonder if this could be provided to Instagram as a suggested feature, one of their devs may be able to explain why they haven't done it yet. Do they have a developer forum?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that what you are seeing is entirely as it appears.  I'm not affiliated with Instagram, and am not familiar with their API, but one of the platforms I designed includes content URLs that are indeed "signed," and do expire, and can be invalidated, yet they appear to be public -- they have no query string because the "signature" is actually an intermediate part of the path, which varies based on who requested it, and allows the URL to be traced back to the client session I originally issued it to.